# supervisord not starting automatically on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: supervisord, ubuntu-20.04

I intalled latest superviosrd

`pip install supervisord==4.2.1`

and then I copied [supervisord init script](https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/debian-norrgard) to `/etc/init.d/supervisord`

`scp /path/to/init_script.sh /etc/init.d/supervisord`

`sudo update-rc.d supervisord defaults`

and then I run:

`sudo service supervisord start && sudo service supervisord status`

got:

```
● supervisord.service - LSB: Starts supervisord - see http://supervisord.org
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/supervisord; generated)
    Active: active (exited) since Sat 2020-08-29 13:03:57 UTC; 19min ago
      Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 1074)
    Memory: 0B
    CGroup: /system.slice/supervisord.service

 Aug 29 13:03:57 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts supervisord - see http://supervisord.org...
 Aug 29 13:03:57 vagrant systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts supervisord - see http://supervisord.org.
```

and then I check

`supervisorctl`

got

```
unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file
supervisor>
```

However, if I manually run

`supervisord`

it will start:

```
redis                            STARTING  
supervisor>
```

Any ideas on how I can make it run automatically on start? and why `sudo service supervisord start` does not start it?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, it is because the [init script](https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts/blob/master/debian-norrgard) I was using has the following:

```
NAME=supervisord
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME  
SUPERVISORCTL=/usr/bin/supervisorctl
```

however, supervisord is installed in `/usr/local/bin/`, so I changed the path, and everything works now.